Validating changing the order of integration when Fubini-Tonelli's theorem does not apply
Consider the Dirichlet integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx.$$
The following method is well-known
\begin{align}
\label{huanxuwenti}
    \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\, dx=&\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-yx}\sin x\, dy\right)\, dx\nonumber\\
    =&\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-yx}\sin x\, dx\right)\, dy\\
    =&\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+y^2}\, dy=\frac{\pi}{2}.\nonumber
\end{align}
However, one can easily prove that \begin{align*}
    \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty |e^{-yx}\sin x|\, dy\right)\, dx=+\infty.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the Fubini-Tonelli's theorem cannot apply here to prove the validity of the change of integration. My question is, why the above method to compute the Dirichlet integral is valid?
Any comments or answers are really appreciated.

Since $|\sin (x) / x|$ is continuous and bounded in $[0, t]$, then it can be concluded that $\sin (x) e^{-x y}$ is integrable in $[0, t] \times \mathbb{R}$, which justifies that we can occupy Fubini in the following way:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^t \frac{\sin (x)}{x} d x & =\int_0^t \sin (x)\left[\int_0^{\infty} e^{-y x} d y\right] d x \\
& =\int_0^t \int_0^{\infty} \sin (x) e^{-y x} d y d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^t \sin (x) e^{-y x} d x d y
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, let us observe that if $I(t, y)=\int_0^t \sin (x) e^{-y x} d x$ then, integrating by parts twice, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(t, y) & =\int_0^t \sin (x) e^{-y x} d x \\
& =-\left.\cos (x) e^{-y x}\right|_{x=0} ^{x=t}-y \int_0^t \cos (x) e^{-y x} d x \\
& =1-\cos (t) e^{-y t}-y\left[\left.\sin (x) e^{-y x}\right|_{x=0} ^{x=t}+y \int_0^t \sin (x) e^{-y x} d x\right] \\
& =1-\cos (t) e^{-y t}-y \sin (t) e^{-y t}-y^2 I(t, y)
\end{aligned}
$$
Solving $I(t, y)$ from the previous equation we obtain
$$
I(t, y)=\frac{1}{1+y^2}-\frac{\cos (t)-y \sin (t)}{1+y^2} e^{-y t}
$$
In summary
$$
\int_0^t \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} I(t, y) \, dy = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + y^2} \, dy - \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t) - y \sin(t)}{1 + y^2} e^{-yt} \, dy. \quad (1)
$$
The next step is to observe the following. First,
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1 + y^2} \, dy = \lim_{z \to \infty} \int_0^z \frac{1}{1 + y^2} \, dy = \lim_{z \to \infty} (\arctan(z) - \arctan(0)) = \frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
Second,
$$
0 \leq \left| \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t) - y \sin(t)}{1 + y^2} e^{-yt} \, dy \right| \leq \int_0^{\infty} \left| \frac{\cos(t) - y \sin(t)}{1 + y^2} \right| e^{-yt} \, dy
$$
$$
\leq \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1 + y}{1 + y^2} e^{-yt} \, dy \leq 2 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-yt} \, dy = \frac{2}{t}.
$$
These last calculations, along with equation (2), indicate that
$$
\left| \int_0^t \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx - \frac{\pi}{2} \right| \leq \frac{2}{t}. \quad (2)
$$
Taking $\lim_{t \to \infty}$, by the squeeze theorem we conclude that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}. 
$$
